# Free themes for commercial use

Tags: themes, licensing

Does anyone here know weather or not a free theme on Wordpress can be used for commercial purposes?

I am using the Pinboard theme.

Would I need to get some sort of licence to operate the website as a business?

Comment: Plugin and Theme recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1217/73) now. The same goes for licensing questions. Please simply read the license text that belongs to the license your free theme is using. Also: If you have a question about some code that is in some sort of repository: Link it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pinboard theme is in the WordPress theme repository and released under the GPL license, this means that you are free to use and redistribute the theme code.

The GPL license gives you....

- the freedom to use the software for any purpose,
- the freedom to change the software to suit your needs,
- the freedom to share the software with your friends and neighbors,
  and the freedom to share the changes you make.

More here: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.html